# Overriding default ItemsPanelTemplate in Silverlight 4?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight-4.0, tabcontrol, itemspaneltemplate

I am trying to override the default template for TabControl in Silverlight. Instead of having the tabs wrap around when they are full, I want to make it so the user can scroll through them, similar to a ListBox. However, Silverlight just ignores everything I put in "ItemsPanelTemplate" and renders the default. Here is the relevant code:

```
    <swc:TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="Tabs">
        <swc:TabControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </swc:TabControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Even if I just put in a regular StackPanel, it still does nothing at all. I am using the Silverlight Toolkit for the tabs, so everything I find online is just for regular WPF and does not work for Silverlight. Thank you all very much for your advice.

Comment: Does it work if you don't specify the `ItemsPanel` at all?

Comment: ScrollViewer isn't Panel, it won't work. You need to redefine the ControlTemplate of the TabControl. Here is the post about scrollable tabitems http://www.dansoltesz.com/post/2010/07/20/Silverlight-tabcontrol-with-scrollable-tabItems.aspx, but it works horrible. Wait some time, I will post the correct code.

Comment: So if you are really interesting in the working TabControl with databinding and two buttons (which provide scrolling left and right), here are the links: C# code: http://pastebin.com/Q0Dx3kAn xaml of the control: http://pastebin.com/E7Nmx7Cs example of usage: http://pastebin.com/aL6t34R8. And don't use the control from my previous comment, because my control doesn't have bugs. After some time I will refactor the code and write a blog post.

Comment: Thanks Vorrtex! That was very helpful. I have my code working now after looking at yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspaneltemplate%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) needs to have a Panel in it as the root element. You have a ScrollViewer. If you want to add a ScrollViewer, you'd have to create a custom ControlTemplate that wraps the ItemsPresenter with a ScrollViewer. The ItemsPresenter will be where the ItemsPanel is shown.

You should be able to get the default Style and ControlTemplate from the Silverlight Toolkit source and tweak it to your needs. Then include your modified version in your application resources or apply it explicitly to individual TabControls.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out you not only need a Panel as a root, you need a TabPanel. It works now.